# Iterate over lists with a particular sum

Tags: python, math, optimization

I would like to iterate over all lists of length `n` whose elements sum to 2.  How can you do this efficiently? Here is a very inefficient method for `n = 10`. Ultimately I would like to do this for `n > 25'.

```
n = 10
for L in itertools.product([-1,1], repeat = n):
    if (sum(L) == 2):
        print L #Do something with L
```

Comment: Can the element values just be `1` and `-1`?

Comment: @lambo477 yes that's right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you only can have a solution of 2 if you have 2 more +1 than -1 so for n==24

```
a_solution = [-1,]*11 + [1,]*13
```

now you can just use itertools.permutations to get every permutation of this

```
for L in itertools.permutations(a_solution): print L
```

it would probably be faster to use itertools.combinations to eliminate duplicates

```
for indices in itertools.combinations(range(24),11):
    a = numpy.ones(24)
    a[list(indices)] = -1
    print a
```

note for you to get 2 the list must be an even length

Comment: `itertools.permutations` will still produce a ton of duplicates. It'd be better to use `itertools.combinations` to choose 11 positions for the -1s.

Comment: Note that it'd be `itertools.combinations(xrange(n), n//2-1)`, and then placing the -1s into the chosen positions. We wouldn't call `combinations` on `a_solution`.

Comment: ahh dang ... now I gotta go open a python interpretter

Comment: oh I see it makes sense now ... @user2357112  it just took me a minute to understand what you were saying

Comment: More generally, given an even `n` (>= 2): `a_solution = [-1] * (n//2 - 1) + [1] * (n//2 + 1)`.

Comment: (Also, you should probably use a number other than 25. 11+13=24. We need an even length here.)

Comment: at @user2357112 lol man thanks ... you helped make my answer much more right than it initially was :P

Comment: That gives me the error `Too many indices for array`. Shouldn't you have to loop over the indices?

Comment: apparently numpy doesnt like tuples ... change it to a list and it should work (see updated code)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to stop your product recursion whenever the remaining elements can't make up the target sum.

Specifically, this method would take your `itertools.product(...,repeat)` apart into a recursive generator, which updates the target sum based on the value of the current list element, and checks to see if the resulting target is achievable before recursing further:

```
def generate_lists(target, n):
  if(n <= 0):
    yield []
    return
  if(target > n or target < -n):
    return
  for element in [-1,1]:
    for list in generate_lists(target-element, n-1):
      yield list+[element]
```

Comment: I think you want `or` instead of `||` ... also this will almost guaranteed exceed pythons recursion stack limit (+1 all the same since it will work fine with smaller lists... and it explains well what the OP should do from a conceptual level)