# Iterate over ratios that sum to unity

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm solving a scientific question where I need to mix `n` compounds in all possible ratios, and want to iterate over only those ratios that sum to unity for some given step size.

For example, for three compounds `(n=3)` and a `step size` of `0.25` I want to iterate over the following ratios

```
(0.00, 0.00, 1.00)  
(0.00, 0.25, 0.75)  
(0.00, 0.50, 0.50)  
(0.00, 0.75, 0.25)  
(0.00, 1.00, 0.00)  
(0.25, 0.00, 0.75)  
(0.25, 0.25, 0.50)  
(0.25, 0.50, 0.25)  
(0.25, 0.75, 0.00)  
(0.50, 0.00, 0.50)  
(0.50, 0.25, 0.25)  
(0.50, 0.50, 0.00)  
(0.75, 0.00, 0.25)  
(0.75, 0.25, 0.00)  
(1.00, 0.00, 0.00)
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930745/iterate-over-lists-with-a-particular-sum) related question, however, it seems like the solutions don't apply for my case.

The following code solves the problem by generating the above ratios, but inefficiently.

```py
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

n = 3
step_size = 0.25

r_range = np.arange(0.0, 1.0+step_size, step_size)
for ratios in it.product(r_range, repeat=n):
    if not np.isclose(sum(ratios), 1.0):
        continue

    print(ratios)
```

Is there an efficient and pythonic way to iterate over only those ratios that sum to unity for arbitrary *n* and step sizes?